# Why there's an "ADD APPLICATION" button when I hover a link of a shared webpage posted on my timeline?

Tags: facebook, share

I want to provide a way for an user to be able share a certain webpage that I'm developing (not a facebook page) on facebook, in his timeline. That simple.

I've tried many things, then I've finally made it work by creating a Facebook App - but actually there's no Facebook App. I believe that it will be useful so I can track the insights, but that aside, I had no reason to have this App. The title, description and image that populate the box on the sharing post come from the Open Graph Tags in the website's index page, not from the settings of the Facebook App related to the webpage.

But then when I hover the link of the shared webpage post, I get a button labeled "ADD APPLICATION" ("Adicionar Aplicativo"), that shouldn't be there, cause there's no actual application.

It will become clear if you see the examples:

http://d.pr/i/SIFs - has an "ADD APPLICATION" button, why?

http://d.pr/i/sE8f - great, no button

These are two websites, that are shared exactly the same way, they have the same Open Graph metatags, same JavaScript SDK code, same FB button code, and they are each one associated with Facebook Apps that have the same settings.

However, only one of them shows the "ADD APPLICATION" button. Why??????

Ultimately, I would like that nothing happend when I hover that link. Just go to the webpage when clicked. Possible?

Thanks a lot, I've been struggling for hours on this.

Comment: Are those both your URLs? is one shared with an app and the other shared manually? is one correctly linked with an app ID via the fb:app_id tag and the other not?

Comment: they're both my URLs, both are connected each one with its respective app ID I checked the fb:app_id and also the ID on the JavaScript SDK code for each page, they're all good. What do you mean 'shared with an app'? Both are shared manually, by clicking on the Like Button, on each respective webpage. There's no real APP actually, I created a facebook app for each webpage only to have the insights (at first actually because a tutorial told I needed to do so)

Comment: I solved my problem, though I haven't answered this particular question I've made. I removed the fb:app_id meta tag on the webpage. Now when I hover the link on the shared post on facebook, no div pops up at all, which is perfect. Thanks Igy